# sed command not working properly in solaris but working in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, solaris

I have following string which is used further in sed command. Its working properly in Linux but NOT working in Solaris

> -bash-3.00$ string="CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLE1(uid)CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLENAMEuid,cid,mid)DATABASE2.TABLENAME(hi,hello)"

**In Linux** box, it outputs properly as below.

```
echo $string | sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
uid,cid,mid)DATABASE2.TABLENAME(hi,hello)
```

**I solaris** , sed search is not working returns full string irrespective of search string match.

```
echo $string | sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLE1(uid)CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLENAMEuid,cid,mid)DATABASE2.TABLENAME(hi,hello)
```

I want the same output to be printed in solaris.

Comment: Which Solaris version? Solaris 11 includes the GNU sed command (the one you use on Linux) as `/usr/gnu/bin/sed` - you can download GNU sed & install it yourself on older releases as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `\+` doesn't work on older sed even on BSD it is not supported. Try this sed:

```
sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]*TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\{1,\}TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'

Comment: is there any functional difference between + and * ?

Comment: @logan `+` means match one or more and `*` means match zero or more.

Comment: @anubhava: So If I use `*` even there is no matched `TABLENAME` it will result the output for above example?

Comment: `[^)]*` will mean 0 or more matches of any character except `)`. You can of course use `[^)]\{1,\}` for 1 or more matches.

Comment: so, if I use `[^)]*` , it will result the data which is not having TABLENAME keyword ?

Comment: No that is not correct, it will still match only if `TABLENAME` is there. `[^)]*` is there to match 0 or more characters between words `CREATESETTABLE` and `TABLENAME`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX `sed` supports only [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (basic regular expressions) in which `+` has *no special meaning*.

One important oddity (relatively speaking) about BREs is that `()` and `{}` *require* `\`-escaping in order to gain their special meaning. Those characters, and *only* those characters, require such escaping. The opposite is required in contemporary (ERE) expressions, `\`-escaping them is required to *disable* their special meaning.

The behaviour of an escaped (`\`) non-special character in a BRE is *undefined* by the specification.

You problem stems from the fact that `\+` (along with `\?`, and `\|` within `\(\)`) are [GNU extensions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions).

These BRE extensions preserve the convention of a `\` prefix, but when GNU `sed` is given the option `-r` it will enable ERE (extended regular expressions) in which `+` has its modern meaning (equivalent to `{1,}`) and the requirement for the extra `\` is removed. Similarly, standard BREs have no special meaning for `?` (or `\?`, equivalent to `{0,1}`), this feature is also enabled with `-r`.

If you use the GNU sed `--posix` option this will disable the various GNU extensions, and your scripts should in general be more portable (though perhaps more convoluted). Well nearly, prior to GNU sed 4.2 (April 2009) the `--posix` option *did not* disable all the BRE extensions, you should make sure to use an up to date version so that non-POSIX features don't creep in.

The most portable way to achieve what you want is with `{1,}`:

```
echo $string | sed --posix -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\{1,\}TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
```